# Generate a 3rd column sequential number based on two previous columns

Tags: excel

I am organizing documents within sharepoint but I'm cataloging the document's location in an excel sheet. I have a "Primary Folder" column and a "Secondary Folder" column (Image). I have created a "Secondary Folder Sequence" column where I am trying to create a sequence based on the previous two columns. For example a document is located within the first (01) Primary Folder and the first (01) Secondary Folder. The first document in 0101 will be 001 in the Secondary Sequence. The next document in these specific primary and secondary folders will be 002. How do I create an equation to generate the sequence? Also, the Primary and Secondary Folders will change, so is there a way to calculate the sequence to start over based on the first two columns?

[image]

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the formula `=IF(D3=D2,E2+1,1)` and continue this scheme for all relevant lines underneath.

That way, the sequence should start counting from 1 whenever you have a new secondary folder number. I hope this is what you are referring to with your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your input. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Great to hear. If you are happy with the solution you can mark the answer as “solved question”, if you want.

Comment: Great, will do.